# SQL - Use dense_rank and group by together

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I was under the impression that when we use rank/row_number/dense_rank, we can NOT use group by, but why does below logic run successfully

```
Select product, type, dense_rank() over (partition by type order by sum(sales) desc) as rnk 
From mytable 
Where date> dateadd(month, -3, getdate()) 
Group by product, type
```

Why am I able to order by sum(sales) within the rank function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the columns which you have used in select statement, it is contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause.

we can use rank function and group by in the same query set but all the columns should be contained in either aggregate function or the Group by clause.

So this query set is giving result by grouping Product and type and giving rank based on highest to lowest sales amount because you have used descending in Order by clause.

Answer (score 4):

Your query is basically equivalent to:

```
select pt.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by type order by total_sales desc) as rnk 
from (select product, type, sum(sales) as total_sales
      from mytable 
      where date > dateadd(month, -3, getdate()) 
      group by product, type
     ) pt;
```

That is, the `dense_rank()` is performed *after* the `GROUP BY`.

This is totally allowed.  So, your understanding that these cannot be used together is incorrect.  However, there are limitations.  The references in the `dense_rank()` need to be columns or expressions that are known *after* the `GROUP BY`.

So, this is allowed in your version:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by type order by sum(sales) desc) as rnk
```

but this is not:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by type order by sales desc) as rnk
```

because `sales` (by itself) is not valid after the `group by`.